# "Свой, а не твой"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как объяснить испаноговорящему человеку, почему мы говорим "скажи СВОЕЙ сестре", а не "скажи ТВОЕЙ сестре"; "я скажу СВОЕЙ сестре, а ты скажи СВОЕЙ, и мы пойдем вчетвером", а не "я скажу МОЕЙ сестре, а ты скажи ТВОЕЙ, и мы пойдет вчетвером"? Как звучит это правило?

Answer (score 2):

Ваш вопрос относится к области стилистики. Действительно, с употреблением возвратного местоимения **себя** и притяжательного местоимения **свой** у иностранцев зачастую возникают проблемы. В подобных случаях возвратное местоимение **себя** следует относить к слову, называющему производителя соответствующего действия. Например: *Комендант велел дворнику отнести вещи жильца к себе* (к коменданту или к дворнику?). Действие коменданта выразилось в том, что он велел, а действие, выраженное инфинитивом *отнести*, относится к *дворнику*; поскольку сочетание *к себе* синтаксически зависит от последнего глагола (*отнести к себе*), то тем самым возвратное местоимение соотносится с существительным *дворник*.

Аналогичное положение может возникнуть при употреблении возвратно-притяжательного местоимения **свой**, поскольку оно тоже может относиться к любому участнику действия. Так, в предложении *Старшая сестра попросила младшую подать ей свою кружку* слово *свою* следует отнести к младшей сестре как производителю действия, выраженного инфинитивом *подать*, с которым связано сочетание *свою кружку*, но оттенок неясности присущ и таким конструкциям.

Возможно синонимическое употребление притяжательных местоимений **мой – свой, твой – свой** и т.п. Употребление притяжательных местоимений **мой, твой, наш, ваш** вместо возможного по условиям контекста **свой** больше подчеркивает связь с соответствующим лицом, в частности при противопоставлении, например: Моей главы коснись *твоей* рукой (Жуковский).

В вашем примере "скажи СВОЕЙ сестре"  словосочетание *своей сестре* относится к глаголу *скажи*, форма которого ясно указывает на производителя действия (2 лицо, ед.ч. - ты). Что касается предложения, где слово СВОЕЙ употреблено два раза, оно и правда звучит не очень.
Учитывая возможность синонимичной замены местоимения СВОЙ притяжательными местоимениями *мой, твой, наш, ваш*, а также то, что фраза обращена к иностранцу, используйте предложенный вами же вариант *"я скажу МОЕЙ сестре, а ты скажи ТВОЕЙ, и мы пойдет вчетвером"*.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Вы очень содержательно описали, в каких случаях и куда относятся эти местоимения. Но хотелось бы уточнить: что ответить иностранцу на вопрос "Зачем вы, вообще, употребляете **свой**, если можно **мой**, **твой** и т.д.?"? Может быть, это больше исторический вопрос...

Comment: Это вопрос, связанный с историей языка. Не во всех языках есть СПЕЦИАЛЬНЫЕ местоимения, указывающие на принадлежность лицу, о котором идет речь. Зачастую в этой роли используют притяжательные местоимения, образованные от личных (МОЙ, ТВОЙ,НАШ, ВАШ), плюс какие-то суффиксы. На мой взгляд, русское СВОЙ более емкое, чем все эти "заменители". А еще корень местоимения СВОЙ присутствует (в исторической ретроспективе) в таких словах, как СВЕКРОВЬ, СВАТ, СВАДЬБА, СВАТАТЬ... Пусть ваши испанские друзья учат русский язык и тогда, может быть, поймут, почему мы любим СВОЙ язык.

Comment: "Свекровь" тут точно не при чем. Слово древнейшее, вероятно даже ностратическое (праиндоевропейское) и к русским местоимениям отношения иметь не может. Тем более, что протокорень, видимо, -ekr-, префиксальные наращения - индоевропейские.
 
Остальное - да, но родство тоже не прямое, а индоевропейское. В славянских эти слова уже разошлись, хотя и сохранили фонетическое сходство.

Comment: Праслав. *svekry «свекровь» развилось из *sve-sry, в котором первая часть *sve- значит «свой, своя», а вторая часть *sry — с неизвестным первонач. знач. по народн. этимол. была заменена элементом *-kry под влиянием слав, кры «кровь» (см. кровь). Таким образом, слово свекры воспринималось в знач. «своя кровь». (Цыганенко)

Comment: А "свекор" тогда как же? И как могло в индоевропейском быть славянское местоимение? 
Не, что-то Цыганенко загнул. Да и Фасмер не подтверждает.

Answer (score 2):

По поводу "почему" мне добавить нечего, разве поспорить о некотрых частностях ситилистики, но это вряд ли актуально в теме РКИ (русского как иностранного).
А вот по поводу "зачем" могу точно сказать, что "свой" никак не избыточно и не стилистикой ограничивается. Местоимения отнюдь не взаимозаменяемы.
Сравните: "Сосед Петра разговаривал с его отцом" и "Сосед Петра разговаривал со своим отцом". И "почувствуйте разницу". Попробуйте объяснить это иностранцу, не так уж всё и сложно.