# "Своей" или "Вашей"?

Tags: стилистика

В общественном транспорте Москвы можно слышать следующее обращение к пассажирам: "В интересах ВАШЕЙ безопасности при обнаружении незнакомых предметов, не трогая их, обратитесь к водителю". Мне кажется, что следовало сказать не "в интересах ВАШЕЙ безопасности", а "в интересах СВОЕЙ безопасности" на том основании, что сама эта рекомендация исходит от одного лица (транспортного агентства или водителя), а исполнителем рекомендуемого действия -"сообщите"- мыслится другое лицо (пассажир). Местоимение ВАШЕЙ было бы уместно в том случае, если субъект сообщения, и субъект упомянутого в нём действия - одно и то же лицо. Например:"В интересах ВАШЕЙ безопасности мы поставили дополнительный поручень".

Comment: *Возьмите свой (ваш) паспорт*. Какой вариант выберете?

Comment: См. также: “Свой, а не твой” https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9

Answer (score 1):

В интересах ВАШЕЙ безопасности при обнаружении незнакомых предметов, не трогая их, обратитесь к водителю.

**Это нейтральный вариант, нет необходимости в использовании местоимения "своей".**

(**У Розенталя**: Употребление притяжательных местоимений мой, твой, наш, ваш вместо возможного по условиям контекста свой больше подчеркивает связь с соответствующим лицом).

**Местоимение "свой"** со значением "принадлежащий производителю действия" желательно использовать **для избежания двусмысленности или для выражения других семантических особенностей.**

**Например:** возьмите ваши документы (документы единственные, выбора нет); возьмите свои документы (вот из этой папки, выбор есть). Я люблю свою маму (подчеркивается близость), я люблю свою/мою лошадку, возможны оба варианта.

**Вывод:** использование местоимение "свой" вместо притяжательных местоимений "мой, твой, ваш, его"  должно иметь какую-то смысловую нагрузку.

Comment: >> *Я люблю свою маму (подчеркивается близость)* Близость подчеркивается как раз в "Я люблю МОЮ маму". Затасканный пример: "Я люблю свой/мой город". Первый вариант -- нейтральный.

Comment: Я говорю о смысловой нагрузке варианта "свой", о его дополнительном значении в каждом конкретном случае, в то же время эта семантика может быть понята по-разному (как очевидно следует из Ваших замечаний). Свой (как я считаю) - это мой собственный,  мне принадлежащий, родной для меня город. Такой вариант встречается чаще.

Comment: Еще раз. "Я люблю свой город" — нейтральная фраза. "Я люблю мой город" — с высоким чувством, с воодушевлением.

Comment: А источник информации какой? Это Ваше личное мнение?

Comment: Помнится, на форуме "Грамоты" видел. И еще где-то... И полностью согласен.

Comment: Доказательств нет,  всё это индивидуальное восприятие, тем более на форуме.  А доказательство надо  начинать с объяснения разницы между местоимениями, а потом указать, как это разница определяет стиль. Иначе такие формулировки ничего не стоят.

Comment: Если 90% хорошо чувствующих язык носителей с этим согласны – других доказательств не требуется.

Comment: Думаю, "мой город" нужно рассматривать отдельно. Это не общий случай как например "мой паспорт". Город мне не принадлежит, "мой город" (в отличие от "город, в котором я живу") не очень употребимо, звучит пафосно, поэтому так же воспринимается и "я люблю мой город".  "Свой город" подчеркивает не мое пафосное отношение к городу, а противопоставление "свой - другой", поэтому более нейтрально.

Answer (score 0):

Иногда возвратные и притяжательные местоимения взаимозаменяемы, иногда возникает двусмыслица.

Поэтому см. с примерами -

Розенталь

**[§170. Возвратные и притяжательные местоимения](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm#%D0%B7_02)**

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, наоборот, именно "вашей" здесь наиболее правильно и несет прямую смысловую нагрузку. А "своей" нейтрально и не подчеркивает принадлежность адресату."Не прячьте ваши денежки" - это доходчиво. А "свои" не лезет тут не только в размер, но и в стилистику.

Вообще использование "свой" и притяжательных местоимений четко прослеживается только для местоимений первого и третьего лица. Там "свой" желательно всегда, когда возможно а все остальное (мой, наш, его, её, их) - только при явном акценте на принадлежность (противопоставлении, например).

А вот "твой/ваш" более или менее осознанно реализуется только в достаточно распространенных предложениях, когда есть несколько потенциальных владельцев или носителей объекта или свойства. Да и то не очень-то последовательно: "перестаньте класть свои вещи на мой стол". ну явно же, что не ваши, говорящий противопоставляет свой-мой, хотя здесь в нейтральной ситуации уместнее бы было "ваши".

Во фразе же про безопасность лучше никак не противопоставлять, "вашей" вполне нейтрально по отношению к носителю, но по стилю весьма требовательно. Выбор видится обоснованным.

В московском транспорте много чего можно услышать, не всему стоить придавать какое-то смысловое значение.