# Употребление притяжательного местоимения "свой"

Tags: местоимения

*Старайтесь выбирать современные компании, которые ориентированы на карьерный рост **своих** сотрудников.*

По Викисловарю у местоимения "своей" есть значение "принадлежащий лицу или объекту, о котором идет речь, или имеющий отношение к этому лицу (объекту)" ([https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/свой](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9)). В словаре Ушакова есть только значение "принадлежащий себе, имеющийся у себя, свойственный себе", подразумевающее принадлежность лицу (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1018862).

Правильно ли употребление притяжательного местоимения "свой" по отношению неодушевлённому существительному вообще и к существительному "компании" в частности в приведённом примере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Старайтесь выбирать современные компании, которые ориентированы на карьерный рост *своих* сотрудников.**

Сравнить: Компания проверила счета, принадлежащие **ее** сотрудникам.

Разница **в производителе** действия: **компании ориентированы и счета принадлежат.**

Местоимение ***свой***  используется преимущественно в том случае, если относится **к производителю действия**, как в первом примере.

Розенталь http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm#%D0%B7_02

Также: ["Своей" или "Вашей"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431036/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9/432332#432332)

["Свой, а не твой"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Comment: "Их сотрудникам" вместо "ее сотрудникам".  Описка?

Comment: Ссылка на "свой" вопрос - описка?

Comment: Извините за неточность.

Comment: На мой взгляд, здесь не стоит примешивать употребление местоимения "его" и указывать ссылки на вопросы, сущность которых совершенно в другом. Мой вопрос о правильности употребления "своих", а не в выборе между "своих" и "их".

Comment: Да там принцип один и тот же, если Вы хотите действительно разобраться в этой теме.  В вашем примере к неодушевленной компании можно применить местоимение "свой", а в другом предложении  к той же неодушевленной компании надо применить местоимение "ее". Значит, для этого существительного дело не в одушевленности, а в другом. Я Вам  это объясняю на примере, но Вам это неинтересно. Делаю вывод, что я зря трачу время.

Comment: Вам уже ответили, что компания может иметь своих сотрудников, этот ответ Вас также не устраивает. Почему? Потому что Вас интересует только конкретный случай, а наше желание раскрыть тему полнее вызывает у Вас непонимание. Значит,  отвечать надо коротко, а именно так: местоимение выбрано верно, см. словарь.

Comment: Вы всё правильно делаете, что полно раскрываете тему. Просто без вашего пояснения я бы не понял сравнения, которое вы сделали в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение построено корректно. Подобные примеры можно найти в словаре.

> СВОЙ... 2. Собственный, составляющий имущество или достояние отдельного лица, учреждения. **Растить свои кадры**. Иметь свою машину, дачу. Раздать всё своё имущество, всю свою зарплату. Купить за свои деньги. У них свой домик в деревне. При заводе своя больница. **Предприятие имеет свой счёт** в валютном банке. Идти в отпуск за свой счёт (без сохранения содержания, оплаты). ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9))

Возможно также употребление притяжательного местоимения "свой" по отношению к другим неодушевлённым существительным:

> СВОЙ... 4. Своеобразный, свойственный только кому-, чему-л. одному, данному или единому. В каждом доме свой запах. В любом движении есть что-то своё, неповторимое. И в осени есть своя прелесть и очарование! ([Там же](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9))

Comment: На мой взгляд здесь местоимение "свой" обозначает отношение, а не принадлежность. Как сотрудники могут составлять имущество, собственность компании? Ваша вторая дефиниция совершенно не подходит к нашему случаю: сотрудники не могут быть свойственны компании, являться её своеобразием.

Comment: Согласен, что сотрудники не рабы и не принадлежат компании, но  "собственный" не обязательно означает принадлежность. Пример "Растить свои кадры" вполне подходит к нашему случаю. А вторая дефиниция действительно не относится к предложению  о сотрудниках. Она отвечает на общий вопрос: "Правильно ли употребление притяжательного местоимения "свой" по отношению неодушевлённому существительному **вообще**"

Comment: Думаю, с точки зрения употребления слова *свой* не нужно проводить границу между отношением и принадлежностью. Общий вывод таков, что нет запрета на употребление местоимения *свой* с неодушевленными.