# Притяжательное местоимение

Tags: местоимения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правило употребления притяжательного местоимения в русском языке (свой, своя, свои).

Пример: **Она очень тихо опускала с кровати ноги в тапочки** или **тихо опускала с кровати *свои* ноги в тапочки.** (В некоторых языках употребление притяжательного местоимения по отношению к своим действиям обязательно.) А здесь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном предложении притяжательное **местоимение не следует употреблять** (оно лишнее), а порядок слов лучше изменить (сначала прямое дополнение, потом обстоятельство):

**Она очень тихо опускала ноги с кровати  в тапочки.**

Вообще говоря, притяжательные местоимения используется только тогда, когда они действительно **необходимы для выражения нужного смысла**. Основные трудности их употребления связаны **с правильным выбором местоимения** (свой, твой, её и т.д.)

**Материалы по теме:**

1) http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=1f34e0cb-d532-431f-880f-93964d427853

2) ["Свой, а не твой"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9)

Comment: первую ссылку нужно поправить